# Explicit growth rate estimation of Gauss-Laguerre quadrature

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, gaussian, numerical-integration, quadrature

The $n$-th Gauss-Laguerre quadrature scheme aims to approximate integral of exponentially decreassing function over $[0;+ \infty[$ by a finite sum, according to:
$ \displaystyle { \int _0 ^{+ \infty} f(x) \, dx \approx  \sum _{i = 1} ^n \omega_i f(x_i) }$,
where $x_1$, $\cdots$, $x_n$ are the roots of the $n$-th Laguerre polynomial $L_n$ and the weights $\omega_1$, $\cdots$, $\omega_n$ are defined by $\omega_i = \dfrac{1}{x_i(L'_n(x_i))^2}$, $1 \leq i \leq n$.

I am interested in this quadrature to apply it to bounded $\mathcal{C}^\infty$-functions
over $[0 ; + \infty [$, with bounded derivatives. In particular, I want to understand the error $\varepsilon_n(f)$ produced by the $n$-th degree Gauss-Laguerre quadrature.

For this purpose, we know three facts:

- The Uspensky theorem states that
  $   \varepsilon_n(f)
      \underset{n \longrightarrow + \infty}{\longrightarrow}
      0
  $ for functions $f$ satisfying $|f(x)| \leq c x^{-(1 + \rho)} e^x$
  for large $x >> 1$ and some $\rho > 0$.
  (See [1])
- A $\mathcal{C}^\infty$-function $f$ is an element of $C_q^p[0,\infty)$
  for all integers $p$ and $q$ such that $0 \leq p \leq q$ (for the notations,
  see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161217/is-there-an-example-where-the-error-of-gauss-laguerre-quadrature-does-not-vanish/295084#295084) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386526/error-in-gauss-laguerre-numerical-quadrature-scheme)).
  According to Mastroianni-Monegati theorem, we have for $q = 2p + 3$:
  \begin{equation}
      \varepsilon_n(f)
      \underset {n \longrightarrow + \infty} {=}
      \mathcal{O} \left ( \dfrac{1}{n^{p - 1}} \right )
      E_{n - p - 1}(\Phi, e^{-\frac{x}{2}})
  \end{equation}
  where $\Phi(x) := x^{p + 3} f(x) \in \mathcal{C}^q([0, + \infty[)$ and
  $E_n(f ; \omega) := \underset{p_n \in \mathbb{R}_n[X]}{\text{inf}}
                      ||\omega (f - p_n)||_{\infty, [0; + \infty[}
  $ denotes the best weighted polynomial approximation, the infimum being taken over all polynomial of degree at most $n$. See [2].
- Moreover, if the $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ function $f$ is such that for all positive integer $n$,
  $||f^{(n)}(x) x^{\frac{n}{2}} e^{-x}||_{\infty, [0;+ \infty[} < + \infty$,
  then $f$ belongs to each Sobolev-type space $W_\infty^n(e^{-x})$, $n \geq 1$,
  defined by
  \begin{equation}
      W_\infty^n(e^{-x})
      =
      \left \{
          f \in L^\infty_{e^{-x}}
          \,,\,
          f^{(n - 1)} \text{ abs. continuous on }(0, \infty)
          \text{ and }
          ||f^{(n)}(x) x^{\frac{n}{2}} e^{-x}||_{\infty, [0;+ \infty[} < + \infty
      \right \}
  \end{equation}
  where
  \begin{equation}
      L^\infty_{e^{-x}}
      =
      \left \{
          f \in \mathcal{C}([0 ; + \infty[)
          \,,\,
          \underset{x \longrightarrow + \infty}{\text{lim}}
          f(x) e^{-x}
          =
          0
      \right \}
      \ .
  \end{equation}
  Consequently, $E_n(f ; \omega) \leq \dfrac{C}{\sqrt{n}^r}$ according to [3], prop. 4.1. p. 112.

  This is the case for example if $f$ is bounded, as well as all its derivatives.

Alltogether allows us to deduce that for any bounded $\mathcal{C}^\infty$-function $f$ with bounded derivative, we have $\varepsilon_n(f) \underset{n \longrightarrow + \infty}{=} \mathcal{O}\left ( \dfrac{1}{n^{\frac{k}{2}}} \right )$ for all positive integer $k$.

My question is therefore :

**Do we have exact estimation of the speedness of the convergence for bounded functions $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with infinite regularity and bounded derivatives?**

As an exemple, we can consider $f_0(x) = \displaystyle { \dfrac {1} {1 + x} }$. Easily computer computations give:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{|c|l|l|}
    \hline
    \text{Degree } n    &   \text{Error } \varepsilon_n(f_0)&   -\ln(\varepsilon_n(f_0)
    \\
    \hline
    1       &   9.634 \cdot 10^{-2}     &   2,339
    \\
    \hline
    2       &   2.491 \cdot 10^{-2}     &   3,692
    \\
    \hline
    4       &   3.045 \cdot 10^{-3}     &   5,793
    \\
    \hline
    8       &   1.326 \cdot 10^{-4}     &   8,927
    \\
    \hline
    16      &   1.394 \cdot 10^{-6}     &   13,483
    \\
    \hline
    32      &   2.025 \cdot 10^{-9}     &   20,017
    \\
    \hline
    64      &   1.840 \cdot 10^{-13}    &   29,323
    \\
    \hline
    128     &   3.380 \cdot 10^{-19}    &   42,531
    \\
    \hline
    256     &   2.526 \cdot 10^{-27}    &   61,242
    \\
    \hline
    512     &   7.940 \cdot 10^{-39}    &   87,728
    \\
    \hline
    1024    &   4.219 \cdot 10^{-55}    &   125,202
    \\
    \hline
    2048    &   4.021 \cdot 10^{-78}    &   178,209
    \\
    \hline
    4096    &   1.107 \cdot 10^{-110}   &   253,182
    \\
    \hline
    8192    &   9.882 \cdot 10^{-157}   &   359,215
    \\
    \hline
\end{array}
\end{equation}

From these computations, one can conjecture that $\varepsilon_{2^n}(f_0) \underset{n \longrightarrow + \infty}{\sim} \exp \left ( -4 \sqrt{2}^n + 2 \sqrt{2} \right )$, from which one can conjecture:
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon_n(f_0)
\underset{n \longrightarrow + \infty}{\sim}
\exp \left ( -4 \sqrt{n} + 2 \sqrt{2} \right )
\ .
\end{equation}

*References:*

[1] J. V. Uspenksy, On the convergence of quadrature formulas related
to an infinite interval, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 30 (1928), 542-559

[2] Mastroianni G., Monegato G., Convergence of product integration rules over $(0, \infty)$
for functions with weak singularities at the origin. Math. Comp. 64, (1995), 237-249.

[3] G. Mastroianni, J. Szabados, Polynomial approximation on the real semiaxis with generalized
Laguerre weights. Stud. Univ. Babes-Bolyai Math. 52 (2007), nr.4, 105--128.